# Fcntl() question about process id

Tags: c, linux, fcntl

I am debugging some code and there is l_pid = 0 always for setting file locks.. It seems odd to me.. Is this correct?Documentation doesnt say about 0 zero value ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`l_pid` is only meaningful when getting the lock status with `F_GETLK`; when setting a lock, if it succeeds then you know what pid owns it.  :)  (And the buffer is returned unmodified it it fails.)